# wxTimerEvent does not always call at the expected interval

Tags: events, delay, wxwidgets

I am using `wxTimerEvent()` to call a function at a certain frequency. But it does not always call the function as expected.

For example, it works fine for a random time duration, and then it does not call the function at all for a few seconds. SHere is my block of code. Please help me  figure out this issue...

```
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
  public:
    ...
    void OnTimer(wxTimerEvent& event);


  private:
    wxTimer *mTimer
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};


wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_TIMER(TIMER_ID, MyFrame::OnTimer)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()


MyFrame::MyFrame()
{
   mTimer = new wxTimer(this, TIMER_ID)
   m_timer.Start(100);    // 100 millisecond interval
}

void MyFrame::OnTimer(wxTimerEvent& event)
{
   // my logic -this is working fine... just set a flag. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Timers are not guaranteed to fire at exactly the specified interval, but for a 100ms timer to not be called for several seconds is not normal at all. I suspect your code doesn't return to the event loop, preventing it from dispatching the timer events. If you're sure this is not the case, you would really need to produce an example reproducing the problem (ideally the smallest possible change to the wxWidgets `minimal` sample) and open a bug report about it (please be sure to mention your wxWidgets version and platform if you do this).